# Spark creating 100s of empty avro files

Tags: apache-spark

I am processing a very large data set using spark. the data is stored as avro files. the data is also organized in a directory structure (/input/yyyy/MM/dd/HH/). So for example the avro files for today will be located in /input/2016/03/18/00 to /input/2016/03/18/23

Now if I process last 2 years of data, there are many many avro files which are processed.

The data processing code is as follows

```
val inputRDD = sc.load("/input", "com.databricks.spark.avro").rdd
val outputRDD = inputRDD.map(foo).filter(_.isDefined).flatMap(x => x).join(anotherRDD).map {
  case (a, (b, (c, d))) => (a, (b, c, d))
}.join(yetAnotherRDD).filter {
  case (a, ((b, c, d), (e, f))) => Math.abs(a - b) <= 2000
}.map {
  case (a, ((b, c, d), (e, f))) => Row(a, d)
}
val outputDF = sc.createDataframe(outputRDD, outputSchema)
outputDF.save(s"/output/${datePath(date)}", "com.databricks.spark.avro")
```

Now when I go inside output using Hue. I see 181 pages and on each page I see many empty avro files.

Not all files are empty... but there are so many empty files.

What if I don't want empty files. (without resorting to "collect")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each input file produces at least one RDD (if a file is big, I might be read in multiple input sequences, and make multiple RDDs).
In you application you execute filters on these RDD, so it is possible that quite some RDDs end up being empty, because all their rows were filtered out. When you save your DataFrame, each RDD will be saved into a different PART file, so an empty RDD will generate an empty RDD file.
To work around this, use `.coalesce(n)`, which will downsize the number of RDDs.
So try something like this on your last line:

```
outputDF.coalesce(200).save(s"/output/${datePath(date)}", "com.databricks.spark.avro")
```

The number to use in coalesce is highly dependent on the size of data. If you have too many RDDs, a lot of performance will be lost due to the communication overhead with the driver; if you have too few RDDs, you might not be using all available executors, which will result in worse-than-optimal performance as well.

Comment: I checked but spark 1.3.0 does not have the colease function. I guess they added it to the data frames later.

Comment: You can use `.repartition(200)` in that case. Just take into note that `.coalesce(200)` would perform better on later versions of Spark.